# Android -Get Selected Date from dialog- Timessquare library

Tags: android, datetime

I am new to android app development. I am  using [timessquare](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) library to show datepicker. i am not able to get the selected date set in my edittext from the dialog.

where should i put et1.setText(sel_date);

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.avail_layout);


    final Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    final Calendar lastYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    lastYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);



    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);

    et1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
          dialogView = (CalendarPickerView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false);
          dialogView.init(lastYear.getTime(), nextYear.getTime()) //
              .withSelectedDate(new Date());
          theDialog =
              new AlertDialog.Builder(avail_activity.this).setTitle("Select a Date")
                  .setView(dialogView)
                  .setNeutralButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        dialogInterface.dismiss();


                    }
                  })
                  .create();
          theDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
              Log.d(TAG, "onShow: fix the dimens!");
              dialogView.fixDialogDimens();
            }
          });
          theDialog.show();

        }

      }

            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timessquare Library provides onDateSelected interface

```
dialogView.setOnDateSelectedListener(new com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
            Log.d("Date Selected", date.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The timesquare library has it's own cell clicklistener

```
@Override
public boolean onCellClicked(Date date) {
   Log.i("DATE", " Date: " + date.toString());
   return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working fine and you are ready to get date try this:

```
dialogView.setDateSelectableFilter(new com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView.DateSelectableFilter()
 {
     @Override
     public boolean isDateSelectable(Date date2)
     {
       Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar2.setTime(date2);
       et1.setText(ConvertToDateStrig(calendar2.getTime()));
       dialog.dismiss();
       return true;
     }
 });
```

To convert date to sting:

```
public static String ConvertToDateStrig(Date date){
        SimpleDateFormat dateformat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        return dateformat.format(date.getTime());
    }
```